Graph get retentionlabel by Id returns 500 unknown error
The Graph API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/labels/retentionLabels/{retentionLabel-id} is broken since 03/12/2024, we have tried with a few different MS365 tenants, they all response 500 with
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"ErrorCode\":\"\",\"Message\":\"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-12-04T09:26:31",
            "request-id": "f18ff0e7-8f0e-4e74-a221-f6e0426d6017",
            "client-request-id": "f18ff0e7-8f0e-4e74-a221-f6e0426d6017"
        }
    }
}

We have tried with different MS365 tenants in Graph Explore. We have consented with the permission needed for the request. This API was working fine until 03/12/2024. We are expecting to get the the retention label information.
